# Server doesn't detect incoming stream in tokio::select loop

Tags: rust, server, stream, rust-tokio

In the first read from the stream, there no problem the function read the stream to the var "name" and printed but after enters the loop the next income stream are not read.
Just enters the tokio::select when stream is closed to print that the connection is closed.

```
 async fn main(){
  let listener = TcpListener::bind("localhost:3001").await.unwrap();
    let (tx, _rx) = broadcast::channel(10);
    loop{
        let (mut stream, socket_addr) = listener.accept().await.unwrap();
        let tx = tx.clone();
        let mut rx = tx.subscribe();
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            let mut name = [0;16];
            stream.read(&mut name).await.unwrap();
            let name = String::from_utf8_lossy(&name).to_string();
            println!("{name} Connected.");
            let (reader, mut writer) = stream.split();
            let mut reader = BufReader::new(reader);
            let mut line = String::new();
            loop {
                    tokio::select! {
                        result = reader.read_line(&mut line)=> {
                            if let Err(_) = result{
                                println!("Connection lost with {name}");
                                break;
                            }                       
                            if line.len() == 0{
                                break;
                            }
                            let mut line = format!("{}: {}", &name, &line);
                            println!("{line}"); 
                            tx.send((line.clone(), socket_addr)).unwrap();
                            line.clear();
                        }
                        result = rx.recv() => {
                            let (msg, other_addr) = result.unwrap();
                            let msg = msg.trim_end_matches('\n');
                            if other_addr == socket_addr {
                            } 
                            if other_addr != socket_addr {
                                let msg = msg.as_bytes();
                                writer.write_all(msg).await.unwrap();
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're doing line-based input, you may want to use the [`tokio_codec`](https://docs.rs/tokio-codec/latest/tokio_codec/) crate with [`LinesCodec`](https://docs.rs/tokio-codec/latest/tokio_codec/struct.LinesCodec.html).

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why, but if you change the read_line function to read, it works.

Comment: Are you sure the input data was LF or CRLF terminated? If not, it'll stall waiting for that.